# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to look deep into the script, but I still can't find the problem.
here's the script

```
global $con;
$a= "SELECT id_list FROM list ORDER BY id_list";
$b = mysqli_query($con, $a);
$c=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);        
    if(mysqli_num_rows($c)==0){
        echo'0';
    }else{
        echo '1';
    }
```

the error that appear is

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Comment: what is the code in your variable $con?

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `mysqli_result` onject as a parameter to `mysqli_num_rows()` so try:

```
mysqli_num_rows($b)
```

read manual here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)